# Creating a new object in JavaScript, getting "Cannot set property '0' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, object

In my code, I am creating a new object based on inputs from a JSON file. The JSON file has a lot of extraneous information, so I first extract the relevant parts into arrays and then use those arrays to make the new object, as a tree.

An example of the format I want the new object to be in is this: (much larger though, it will have uneven layers like below)

```
    { 
       "name" : "flare",
       "children" : [
          {
            "name" : "solar"
            "name" : "photon"
          }
       ]
       "name" : "system",
       "children" : [
          {
            "name" : "axios"
          }
       ]
     .....
     }
```

The first layer is in an array called "packs" and the second children layer is in an array called "deps". (packLen and depsLen is also declared previously). My code is below:

```
let treeBe = {};
for (i=0; i<packLen; i++) {
    treeBe.parent[i] = {name: packs[i]};
    for (j=0; j<depsLen; j++) {
        treeBe.parent[i].children[j] = {name: deps[i,j]}
    }
}
```

I am getting an error "Cannot set property '0' of undefined", but that is appearing within the second loop. This object is based upon the array, which is based on the incoming JSON file. I do not know the size ahead of time, so I do not know how to define it ahead of time. Why is the second layer having the undefined problem and not the first?

Thank you in advanced.

EDIT:
I had to change these 3 lines of code:

```
let treeBe = {"parent" : [], "children" : []}

treeBe.parent[i] = {name: packs[i], "children": []}

treeBe.parent[i].children[j] = {name: deps[i,j]}
```

Comment: where is `parent`?

Comment: I was trying to declare `parent` in the first loop. I kept working it and put `parent` in the initialization. `children` could be declared when the first name is assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I had to change these 3 lines of code:

`let treeBe = {"parent" : [], "children" : []}`

`treeBe.parent[i] = {name: packs[i], "children": []}`

`treeBe.parent[i].children[j] = {name: deps[i,j]}`